# React and data binding

Tags: reactjs

I've got a parent and child component pair that has me stuck with data binding.

A top level component will render a new `Question` component:

```
<Question updateScore={this.updateScore} />
```

The `updateScore` method will just update a hash with numerical values. That's not too important. The question component is pretty straightforward:

```
var Question = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { options: blahBlahBlah };
  },

  updateScore: function(optionLabel) {
    this.props.updateScore(optionLabel);
  },

  render: function() {
    var optionList = this.state.options.map(function(option) {
      return (
        <QuestionItem optionLabel={option.optionLabel} description={option.description}
                      updateScore={this.updateScore} key={option.key} />
      );
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <ul>
        {optionList}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

The question item componenet is even simpler:

```
var QuestionItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.props.updateScore.bind(this, this.props.optionLabel)}>
        {this.props.description}
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

The problem is with the current implementation, the console spits out this error:

```
"Warning: bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance. See Question"
```

Also if I log out the value of the score that's being updated then I see that it doesn't update any of the keys but inserts an undefined:

```
{ labelOne: 0, labelTwo: 0, undefined: NaN }
```

How should I go about binding this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

React actually [auto-binds methods to the current component](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html):

```
scope.props.updateScore.bind(null, this.props.optionLabel)
```

By providing `null` instead of `this` you'll allow React to do its own thing.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: This answer was posted before the question edit. I'm keeping it because it could help others in the future**

When you do `()` after the function you're passing the result of your function to the Question component. That way, when you call your `this.props.updateScore` you're only getting the result of the function instead of executing it.

You need to pass its reference down so the Question component can execute or bind to it. This way when you call `this.props.updateScope` you will get a function and can execute it using `this.props.updateScope()` or bind to it `this.props.updateScope.bind(this)` for example.

Remove those `()` like here:

```
<Question updateScore={this.updateScore} />
```

And you should be good to go

Comment: Whoops that was a typo. It doesn't have those parens.

Comment: Ah I see, should I delete my answer then? @Simpleton

Comment: No I still think your words may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is legitimate since your code is binding `QuestionItem` instead of `Question` to `updateScore()`. I'd suggest one of two options:

1) Since you have the `optionLabel` property in `Question`, bind the function there so it can used the correct `this`.

```
var optionList = this.state.options.map(function(option) {
  return (
    <QuestionItem optionLabel={option.optionLabel} description={option.description}
                  updateScore={this.updateScore.bind(this, option.optionLabel)} key={option.key} />
  );
}.bind(this));
```

2) If you want to keep the binding within `QuestionItem`, use a wrapper function like so

```
var wrapperFunc = function(optionLabel) {
      this.props.updateScore(optionLabel);
}.bind(this, this.props.optionLabel);

return (
  <li onClick={wrapperFunc}>
    {this.props.description}
  </li>
);
```